# Copy collection in mongodb by php without admin privilege

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to let mongo user without admin privilege to execute collection copy at a php application. I know `db.source.copyTo(target)` requires admin privilege, and I used `db.getCollection(coll).find().forEach( function(d) {db.getCollection(coll2).insert(d)});` instead, and it worked find at a mongo shell. But in php, I use mongo::execute method with the same user to run this script and it returns `{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }`.

```
$db->execute('function (coll, coll2) { return db.getCollection(coll).find().forEach( function(d) {db.getCollection(coll2).insert(d)});}', array( $from, $to ));
```

I did some search and found it's because the underlying execution of php "execute" also uses "eval" which requires admin privilege. Is there any other way in PHP to do mongo collection copy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used shell_exec to execute this shell command to fulfill this function.

$cmd = "xxx/bin/mongo ip:port/'db' -u 'uuu' -p 'ppp' --eval \"db.getCollection('hello').find().forEach( function(d) {db.getCollection('hello_copy').insert(d)});\"";

$shell_exec($cmd);

But in many production environments, shell_exec is disabled at php.ini. If so, you need to enable shell_exec at php.ini and make sure the shell command is escaped from malicious attacks.